# log4j filtering based on EAR

Tags: logging, log4j, weblogic, filtering

Our app is currently logging using Log4j at application level. There are at least **8 EAR** files, which are deployed when the server runs. All **8 EAR**'s are logging into **File1.log** file. I want to separate 1 ear. For example, 7 EAR files should conitnue logging in **File1.log** file however, the 8th one say **ABCD.EAR** should log into **ABCD.LOG** file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe i have figured it out. Though it was an easy solution but all the examples across the internet was based on .properties file and i was looking for .xml file configuration.

1. First of all, I need an appender

   < appender name="ABCD" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
       < param name="File" value="./logs/ABCD.log" />
       < param name="Append" value="true" />
       < param name="MaxFileSize" value="100MB" />
       < param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
       < layout class="provision.services.logging.PSPatternLayout">
           < param name="conversionPattern" value="%d %D %S %-5p {%P} %#: [%-17c{5} %T] %m%n" />
       < /layout>
   < /appender>
2. Then i need to tell the logger, what class heirarchy to log using this. The ABCD.ear has file herirarchy as project.abcd.*. So i added this line in log4j.xml

   < logger name="project.abcd">
       < level value="INFO"/>
       < appender-ref ref="ABCD"/>
   < /logger>

I hope this would be helpful for someone else.

P.S:
Whats wrong with XML Formating in edit box?? ... my xml wasn't visible before, then i had to add spaces and now its not "formatted" properly .. :s

Comment: I am still looking for a problem. There are few classes which doesn't fall under **project.abcd.*** but they are still under **ABCD.EAR**. How can i add logging based on EAR not on CLASS HEIRARCHI